# eval not evaluating echo?

Tags: bash, eval

I'm trying to write something that stores an API access token in a bash variable, so I'm modelling it on `ssh-agent`, where you use `eval`.

**ssh-agent**

If you run `ssh-agent` by itself, it outputs something like the following:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXXXXXXX/agent.NNNNN; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=NNNNN; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid NNNNN;
```

And if you run it with `eval $(ssh-agent)`, it outputs:

```
Agent pid NNNNN
```

...and the `eval` results in the environment variables being set in your current shell.

**my script**

The end of my script looks like this (`$JSON` came from some earlier curl command):

```
cat <<EOF
API_ACCESS_TOKEN=$(echo $JSON | jq '.access_token')
API_EXPIRES_AT=$(echo $JSON | jq '.expires_at')
export API_ACCESS_TOKEN API_EXPIRES_AT
echo OK
EOF
```

When I run it with `eval $(./auth)`, it's correctly setting `$API_ACCESS_TOKEN` and `$API_EXPIRES_AT` (so the `eval` works), **but it's not printing "OK"**.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at that output from `ssh-agent` again.  You are missing the terminating `;` after each command.

With these, the script will do what you want.

Without the semicolons, the shell will execute the commands in the string (the here-document) as one command with the newlines removed.

Answer (score 3):

This, too, seems a word-splitting issue. The script outputs (essentially) this:

```
VAR=foo
export VAR
echo OK
```

But since you used an unquoted command substitution, it gets split, and given to `eval` as distinct words, as if you entered:

```
eval VAR=foo export VAR echo OK
```

After that, Bash's `declare` shows that `echo` and `OK` are exported, though not set:

```
$ declare -p echo
declare -x echo
```

So you'd need to either quote the command substition (`eval "$(./auth)"`) or put the semicolons in there as `ssh-agent` does.